# Cannot add items to Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I created an activity from which I can add product title,description,price and image to the database, but when I click on submit button nothing happens. I've given internet permission, enabled Firebase authentication (Email/Password and Google).

I can't find any error, in logcat I found these, but I don't know how to resolve:

```
DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@f09391f
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
```

Also the database rules is :

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

and Storage rules are:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

My Activity Code is:

```
public class createPost extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageButton m_SelectImage;
    private EditText mProdTitle;
    private EditText mProdDesc;
    private EditText mProdPrice;
    private Button mSubmit;
    private static final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 1;
    private Uri mImageUri = null;
    private StorageReference mStorage;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private ProgressDialog mProgress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_post);
        m_SelectImage = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.p_image);
        mProdTitle = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.p_title);
        mProdDesc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.p_description);
        mProdPrice = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.p_price);
        mSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.p_submit);

        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products");

        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);

        m_SelectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,GALLERY_REQUEST);
            }
        });
        mSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startPosting();
            }
        });
    }

    private void startPosting() {
        mProgress.setMessage("Adding new Post");
        final String title_val = mProdTitle.getText().toString().trim();
        final String desc_val= mProdDesc.getText().toString().trim();
        final String price_val = mProdPrice.getText().toString().trim();
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title_val) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(desc_val) && TextUtils.isEmpty(price_val) && mImageUri!=null)
        {
            mProgress.show();
            StorageReference filePath = mStorage.child("Products").child(mImageUri.getLastPathSegment());
            filePath.putFile(mImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Uri downloadURL = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                    DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();
                    newPost.child("Title").setValue(title_val);
                    newPost.child("Description").setValue(desc_val);
                    newPost.child("Price").setValue(price_val);
                    newPost.child("Product_Image").setValue(downloadURL.toString());
                    mProgress.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(createPost.this,"Posting Complete",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(createPost.this,"Error Occured"+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode==GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {
            mImageUri=data.getData();
            m_SelectImage.setImageURI(mImageUri);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I can't find any error in my code (if any).

Comment: change the database rule to read:true and write:true

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @PeterHaddad changed the rules, still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your mistake. A missing ! in your condition. Change this

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title_val) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(desc_val) && TextUtils.isEmpty(price_val) && mImageUri!=null)
```

to this:

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title_val) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(desc_val) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(price_val) && mImageUri!=null)
```

Comment: let me try this.

Comment: also, this got me to another question, how to check the value of mImageUri is either null or not?

Comment: it worked, thanks a lot. but this was my silly mistake.

Comment: No Problem ;) And your check for null of mImageUri is correct!

Comment: hey, i have another question, in some apps, when i press the back button, it asks to quit the application or not? how can i implement that?

Comment: you better start a new question, because this is off topic here ;)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a user signed in, when you click on submit button?
You can check that by adding following code to onCreate():

```
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            Log.d(getSubClassTAG(), "onAuthStateChanged: singed in: " + user.getUid());
        } else {
            Log.d(getSubClassTAG(), "onAuthStateChanged: signed out: ");
        }
    }
};
```

If not, you have to sign in a user like following:

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmailAndPasswort: onComplete: " + task.isSuccessful());

        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmailAndPassword: failed ", task.getException());
        } else {
            //signin was successful
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: yes there is a user signed in,after doing signin, this activity opens where user can and items to database,but nothing happens when i click on submit button

Comment: Does the progress bar show up, when you press submit button?

Comment: then the condition of your if-statement is likely false. Are all EditText fields filled? Is mImageUri == null maybe?

Comment: yes all edit texts are filled and i have selected an image, which also shows up in the image button

Comment: yes, but have you checked the value of mImageUri itself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169540/discussion-between-anish-arya-and-locdoc01).